# Alternative to ADSI for adding user to admin group

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

```
#Set directory to administrators of $ComputerSN
$AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerSN/Administrators,group"

#sets user by domain and provided ACEID
$User = [ADSI]"WinNT://USA/$UserName,user"

$AdminGroup.add($User.Path);
```

Is there an alternative to the code above that does not leverage `$AdminGroup.add($User.Path)`? I am trying to create a job with a progress bar displaying a timer when adding the user to an administrators group, but the `.add` cmdlet does not work in a Job.

When I'm trying to use

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity <SAMAccountName> -Members <SAMAccountName>
```

I get this error:

> add-adgroupmember : Cannot find an object with identity: '' under: ''

I guess I am not sure how to pass the information to `Add-ADGroupMember` or if there is an alternative to the syntax for adding a user leveraging ADSI that is compatible with a job...

Or maybe there is a better solution to what I am trying to do.

Thanks in advance for any comments!

Comment: The builtin Administrators group on a given domain member is not an AD group - it's a local group. You probably want to use `Add-LocalGroupMember`, perhaps in conjunction with `Invoke-Command`

Comment: Thank you Mathias!  I knew it was a local group, I did not realize it does not register using Add-ADGroupMember.  I will try this out and report back!

Comment: That worked as expected.  Thanks again for clarifying that for me @MathiasR.Jessen!

Comment: That's great to hear! I'd recommend posting an answer below, documenting how you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Mathias, the local administrators group is not an AD group, thus should be manipulated using a combination of `Add-LocalGroupMember` and `Invoke-Command` as demonstrated below:

```
Invoke-command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
     Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member $UserName
}
```

Simply change the `Add-LocalGroupMember` to `Remove-LocalGroupMember` to remove a local group member.